# Where are global setting stored by fossil?

Tags: version-control, file-location

The fossil-scm settings wiki speaks of global settings as follows:

> You can also set a setting globally on your local machine. The value will be used for all repositories cloned to your machine, unless overridden explicitly in a particular repository. Global settings can be set by using the -global option on the fossil settings command.

See the following: http://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/trunk/www/settings.wiki

Where does fossil store these global settings once set?  I have verified global settings work, but I cannot locate a file anywhere in my user folder or anywhere else on my system.

Comment: Well, it would have helped if you had specified that your platform was Windows. As on Linux, the location of the file is `~/.fossil`.

Comment: I confess that I strategically left that out because I work on many platforms and hoped the answer for one might lead to the answer for another.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized Process Monitor (Microsoft Sysinternals) would help me figure this out.

I located a SQLite database here on my Windows 7 box:

`"C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local_fossil"`

I opened it with SQLite Database Browser and confirmed my global settings were contained therein.

Cheers!